# Postgresql slow - how best to begin tuning?

Tags: performance, postgresql

My postgresql server seems to be intermittently going down. I have PgBouncer pool in front of it, so the website hits are well managed, or were until recently.

When I explore what's up with `top` command, I see the `postmaster` doing some `CLUSTER`. There's no cluster command in any of my cronjobs though. Is this what `autovacuum` is called these days?

How can I start to find out what's happening. What commands are the usual tricks in a PGSQL DBA's toolbox? I'm a bit new to this database, and only looking for starting points.

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to know about DBA stuff, ask on [dba.se]

Comment: Thank you. I'm picking up on the way these multiple sites of StackOverFlow are structured. Many questions seem to be asked universally in the main site. But, roger that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, autovacuum never runs `CLUSTER`. You have something on your system that's doing so - daemon, cron job, or whatever. Check individual user crontabs.

`CLUSTER` takes an exclusive lock on the table. So that's probably why you think the system is "going down" - all queries that access this table will wait for the `CLUSTER` to complete.

The other common cause of people reporting intermittent issues is checkpoints taking a long time on slow disks. You can enable checkpoint logging to see if that's an issue. There's lots of existing info on ealing with checkpointing performance issues, so I won't repeat it here.

The other key tools are:

- The `pg_stat_activity` and `pg_locks` views
- `pg_stat_statements`
- The PostgreSQL logs, with a useful `log_line_prefix`, `log_checkpoints` enabled, a `log_min_duration_statement`, etc
- `auto_explain`